# Google Recaptcha doesn't work on localhost

Tags: recaptcha

Google Recaptcha is not working on localhost. I have used the admin console to create a key just for localhost and I have even disabled domain validation under advanced settings. I still get an error indicating that localhost is not on the list of supported domains. Code is below

in the head tag of HTML

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

In the body tag of HTML

```
 <div class='form-group'>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" 
  datasitekey="6Leefj0UAAAAAAb8CMhdkGZxmVVhKGxMGkUPqB6z"></div>
</div>
```

The above site key doesn't have domain validation enabled (I have disabled it out of desperation). So anyone should be able to replicate this error using it. How do I get Google Recaptcha to work?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq  scroll down to the section titled: I'd like to run automated tests with reCAPTCHA. What should I do? The give you some keys that you can use for testing